# getting error while running .net core application , error - System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'C:\##\##\wwwroot\'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

Getting error while running the .net core applicaiton. Runtime exception throwing saying

> Error  System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'C:####\wwwroot'
> getting error in program.cs file in the below line .

```
Below is the program.cs file
public static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);//Error
```

*Below is the launchsetting json file*

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:10598",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "WebAutomation": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5206",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think the error is pretty forward, what is the question? Where do you set the folder?

Comment: You code looks fine. Do you try to create a new project to see if you meet the error again?

Comment: What's your problem scenario? Could you explain it more?